How to generate a Symmetric Key on the Secure Enclave of iOS devices and use it to sign data
I'm working on a secure app that uses the user's master password to derive a symmetric key to encrypt all the user information. I want to add FaceId support now, and the approach I was thinking of was to generate a symmetric key on the Secure Enclave, and use that symmetric key to encrypt the symmetric key derived from the user password, and store that last key on the KeyChain. So the process would be:
1 - Generate a symmetric key on the Secure Enclave requiring biometrics to access it.
2 - Derive the symmetric key from the user password and store it on the KeyChain (preferabley) or disk, in both cases encrypted with the symmetric key from the Secure Enclave.
3 - Finally, when the user wants to access the app, I would trigger a FaceId scan, to access the symmetric key on the Secure Enclave and use it to decrypt the symmetric key derived from the user password, thus being able to decrypt the user information.
The problem I'm having is that, after careful study of the Secure Enclave documentation, I only see how to generate a public-private key pair in the secure enclave with a call to the method:
func SecKeyCreateRandomKey(
    _ parameters: CFDictionary,
    _ error: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?>?
) -> SecKey?

See the official documentation here and here.
but I have found no documentation on how to generate a Symmetric Key.

Are Symmetric keys not supported on the Secure Enclave?
If no, is there a way to convert a public-private key pair to a symmetric key? Is it advisable?
If no, should I just use the public-private key pair to encrypt/decrypt the symmetric key derived from the password and that's it.
If no, what would be the best approach to add FaceId instead?

Thanks in advance.

The question is more appropriate on security-SE, which has an iOS tag. It's migrated there.

Notice that a symmetric key can't sign (since signature verification is against a public key and a message). Instead, a symmetric key can create a Message Authentication Code, which can be recomputed and checked using the original private key (and the message).
